how can i remove loop invariant in this
In the code below i have to remove all loop-invariant computations, my friend has given me this problem and I am not able to solve it for a long time.
x = 10
a = 20
for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
    b = a * i;
    c = x * a;
    d = b + c;
    y = c * 10;
}

I have to remove all the loop-invariants

Did you ask your friend to explain it to you?

yeah now he also can't solve it, his professor gave it to him

Is the problem that you're unclear on what a loop invariant is in general, what the invariants are for this particular loop, or just which statements can be moved out of the loop because of that?

What's a "loop variant"???

Are you actually asking what's the final value of the 7 variables? You could print them, though it would be easy to figure out by walking through the code. Take a piece of paper and create a column for each of the 7 variables. Then walk through the code while updating the current value of each variable on your piece of paper.

You have to remove all the loop invariants. Look it up. @ikegami

Strange friends you keep. Your "friend" isn't also your computing tutor perhaps?

Avoid irrelevant tags.  It does not help your question finding the correct audience.

Loops invariants are conditions that are true before and after each loop pass. You can't remove them. That makes no sense.  But knowing the loop invariants can allow you to optimize parts of the loop away. In this case, you can optimize the entire loop away. If that's what you want, then you are actually asking for the final value of the 7 variables. So again I ask what you are trying to achieve.


how can i remove loop invariant in this

Any expression that is loop-invariant (i.e. does not change value inside the loop), calculate and assign to a variable before the loop.  Use that variable in the loop (if necessary).
Any expression involving i or dependent on i is not loop invariant.  Therefore the invariants are c and y.
y is not truly loop-invariant as it is not used in the loop at all.  It is rather loop-independent, and could be calculated before or after the loop, or even in parallel to it.
Moreover unless b andd are somewhere declared volatile (in say C, though this is clearly pseudocode), the loop does nothing with the intermediate calculation and only the value of the final loop iteration is available to do anything useful. So you could eradicate the loop entirely.  And even the calculations.  Ultimately:
x = 10
a = 20
c = 200
y = 2000
b = 180
d = 36000

I am not sure whether that is intentionally a "trick" question or an error in the question.  It is common for such contrived exercises to be flawed.  It is better to learn from something more realistic.

Maybe in the code below you should delete all loop-invariant computations?
x = 10
a = 20
c = x * a;
y = c * 10;
for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
    b = a * i;
    d = b + c;
}


Strictly the question was how to do it?, not do it for me.  You offered a solution to the problem, not an answer to the question.  And likely did someone's homework for them without teaching anything.

Perhaps the problem was that the task was misheard. Otherwise, a person would have solved it on their own.

The title is clear and uses the correct term.  The use of "variant" in the question body is clearly a typo.  You might not "solve it on your own" if you did not know what "loop invariant" meant.    Look at it this way; the OP's "friend"/ tutor asks them to explain their solution - what do they say? They may still be clueless.

You can still go one step further and set b = a * 9; and d = a * 9 + c, it's all loop-invariant.

I didn't pay attention to the title. I saw the word variant in the question twice and then in the comment.

Understood. Fair enough.
